# Constraining a function argument type in TypeScript for creating a pipeline that returns a goal function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a function pipeline that creates a series of checks/guards and then accepts a function and returns a function that either returns early or calls the accepted function. Something like this:

```js
// A generic function type. The goal is to have the pipeline work with any type of function
interface GoalFunctionType { (): string }

// Pipeline instantiation and usage `checkSomething` and `provideName` are example functions in the pipeline, they are not implemented here.:
const p = new FunctionPipeline<GoalFunctionType>()
const passedInFunction = ({ name }: { name: string }) => "Hello " + name
const goalFunction: GoalFunctionType = p.checkSomething().provideName().finally(passedInFunction);
```

The pipeline checks along the way can trigger an early return in `finally`. They could optionally create additional arguments for function passed into finally as in `provideName` above (but implementations below haven't gotten that far yet).

I'm getting stuck by the type checker on the `finally` function. I want the type checker to ensure that the function passed in

- has the same return type as the `GoalFunctionType`
- accepts the same arguments as `GoalFunctionType`
- accepts additional, pipeline-generated arguments as named arguments in the first argument (not implemented here)

Here's a minimal implementation ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-function-pipeline-ltjtqt)) that isn't compiling without errors/warnings:

```js
class FunctionPipeline<FunctionType extends (...args: any[]) => any> {
  finally(
    fn: (...args: Parameters<FunctionType>) => ReturnType<FunctionType>
  ): FunctionType {
    return (...args) => {
      return fn(...args);
    };
  }
}

interface LoaderFunction {
  ({ name }: { name: string }): string;
}

const goalFunction = new FunctionPipeline<LoaderFunction>().finally(
  ({ name }) => {
    const result = `Hello ${name}`;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
);

const app = document.getElementById("app");
if (app) app.innerHTML = goalFunction({ name: "World" });
```

To implement pipeline-generated arguments, the finally function would be more like this and hopefully with specific type:

```js
fn: (pipelineArgs: GeneratedArgsType, ...args: Parameters<FunctionType>) => ReturnType<FunctionType>
  ): FunctionType {
  return (...args) => {
    // example: this.generatedArgs == { name: "Nathan" };
    return fn(this.generatedArgs, ...args);
  };
}
```

There are two compiler errors with the `functionPipeline.finally` method.

Error on first return:

```
Type '(...args: any[]) => ReturnType<FunctionType>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionType'.
  '(...args: any[]) => ReturnType<FunctionType>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'FunctionType', but 'FunctionType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
```

Error on second return:

```
(parameter) args: any[]
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<FunctionType>'.
```

Can you help me figure out the right types here to accomplish my goals above? Here's the [minimal example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-function-pipeline-ltjtqt). If you want to see more code, [check out this longer example that provides more application context and usage in the Remix framework](https://gist.github.com/jfeaver/c5d9c4a9e66809f2fad3c61cbd0c48c4).

Comment: Instead of a longer external example, could you provide a plaintext [mre] in the body of the question that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE?  I don't know what `checkThis()` is supposed to be but it's not part of the code as shown here.

Comment: @jcalz, I've added a minimal reproducible example at the center of my question and have clarified that `checkSomething` and `provideName` are shown as example pipeline functions. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOxK7N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what is missing?

Comment: That seems to be working the way I want it to. I'm surprised since I tried something very similar to that in my own attempts. My thought was that adding the additional types where you have them would constrain the `any` enough to make things work. It seems that was correct but I didn't get it quite right. Thank you for lending a hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is producing an error because there is no guarantee that `FunctionPipeline<F>` can produce a value of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `F` when you call `finally()`.  `F` can be any subtype of any function type, including a function with extra properties on it:

```
function foo(x: string) {
    return x.length;
}
foo.strProp = "hey";
const gf = new FunctionPipeline<typeof foo>;
gf.finally(foo).strProp.toUpperCase() // no compiler error, but:
//  RUNTIME ERROR  gf.finally(...).prop is undefined
```

That blows up at runtime because `typeof foo` is known to have a `strProp` property, while your implementation of `finally()` does not.  Oops.

---

You don't really care about the function type `F` anyway; just its [argument tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and return type.  If you weren't relying on manually specifying the type argument when calling `new FunctionPipeline<F>()`, then I'd say you should refactor to use the two types you care about:

```
class FunctionPipeline<A extends any[], R> {
    finally(
        fn: (...args: A) => R
    ): (...args: A) => R {
        return (...args) => {
            return fn(...args);
        };
    }
}

const goalFunction = new FunctionPipeline<[{ name: string }], string>().finally(
    ({ name }) => {
        const result = `Hello ${name}`;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
);
```

That is more straightforward because, for example, `finally()` produces a function of type `(...args: A) => R`.

---

But, assuming that's not acceptable, another approach is to compute `A` and `R` from `F` and throw away `F` entirely.  Like this:

```
class FunctionPipeline<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> {
    finally(
        fn: (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>
    ): (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
        return (...args) => {
            return fn(...args);
        };
    }
}
```

So a `FunctionPipeline<F>`'s `finally()` method returns a value of type `(...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>`, and does not claim to return a value of type `F`.  That fixes the problem I showed with `foo`:

```
function foo(x: string) {
    return x.length;
}
foo.strProp = "hey";

const gf = new FunctionPipeline<typeof foo>;
gf.finally(foo).strProp // compiler error! 
// Property 'strProp' does not exist on type '(x: string) => number'
```

Now the compiler doesn't think `gf.finally(foo)` has a `strProp` property. And your example code also works:

```
const goalFunction = new FunctionPipeline<LoaderFunction>().finally(
    ({ name }) => {
        const result = `Hello ${name}`;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpeAGxCiiQDEBXYeAFwwHtgAFDGCcjYBAA8DJqw4AVAJ68kEAB7MIwACY0AFADptINFigAuJCGBSA2gF0AlEgC8APmOnHBYqXcAzASHLkp6oncg0g9gIy0dPUMkTl1wCCU0KBFGFnZgaV57GwckACUE+jQMmWFRNMlS+0DgpCsjcvES2VdaoLRC4qR1CM1dfSMTKRyXGrbgjuYi4CRQ3v6oKwBuMfGAXxsqJykVt2C11YPCVY9Uptm2NnV5IyhmTGAsG1bayemkeU1yZSxmAAtdu4jp5Lpo7mhOGg2DA7EgAER-CBSOG7VbwDh3JBYDywwQAdzoZ3S3F4-EEQmYpTYOI8l3sgNI2M0XlAvn8tLYVjB90h0M0zDYAFUYLw0ABhKgQdQ2AD0MqQgF4NwClO1iPMzvGzelyYFCYRgaIwVBAWRAVEQiEciKBILAEMhIcaIGgQAAjb54NGUaiEsTEnh8ATCACCckUyjU20sABp8qM9kEWT4-AF421QuFtH0okYgyN8qt3PVupmFjm83kPanXp0ZvMonmXuN2jXZsA6-plgXamsGftDub4+jgJisGwfI10riIASJxwSQHyWZcEhrRBbvcBDg1hYY+DN-ZperWcmuyR1MvV0gNnY402SEPMR0oPRyMxYQADAASfHIbCQABJcFXNZ317cYHzYb4vjYLB1CfF9mE7KsJhbeDXzAoFViQtEMTfEARVhFQ2HgehIGAZhNCwBIAFFvjI5gACEpAASRUdQ4XwmA4SQ9wMBxdROM2EVNAEQQ0E-CQAFkABlYVHcciQ4c8V3iIw4QAdTYNByBUOEryQo5V1tRBUAAaxAKQg3IKA-1cT0qBoWcuH9MkylDJRVA0Ets0jawb22W9akTTVTwTMJi0iAYYjiSBEmSWhsn8gopmKTIymqZC6gzSLoliZ1YqdeLEtyZLpjSkRAqbN4unbRZ-MbO8SGqmY5m8jsMO7DqSGBUhLXjAREg8O0kGkscjTQJzKzaZTLzWIwL1UpA90efT1weLAwL69wHzfeTyEm2wV2nH0Kmc0lAyEUaQHGpyDy5YKT0ymb4n0+rQu23CkDQt9Dq-H8-0A4DQPe0gIKg39YO+ni72ar7oAQrqryw1FB0+zjCOI0jlAoqjmFoiB6KY1j2M47iwL47pBOMYTRKdCSZLksd9sUtsFsgNTNO03T9JRzwWYuK4biWjdHmeULYc+b5Hn+TaTlBcFeRhQ6ESRFEBw+4ddpxQ78ROpp51cikqRpOkwKZB72UuLkFd1JA5TkNAoTQABCJBVntxWnUpJAAHIbehH2kCI6AVzYN8FH1N8OCQSlZB9641s3PNgFIl0nR9gcLSAA)

Comment: Thanks again @jcalz. I do want to specify the function type as in the second part of your answer. For my particular application, developers know the function type quite well but not the argument/return types as much. Things are still working .